# Django adding new attribute to WSGIRequest

Tags: django, django-views

Hey im kinda new to Django and the whole Views/Request process.
So I noticed i got the auth_user inside the request object due to the User middleware I had inside the settings file, and anywhere i have the request, i can call the user object with request.user

I kinda have a similar modal/object that is pretty important and I saw how to create a basic middleware but I'm not for sure how to replicate similar functionality where I'd be able to access that specific object inside the request like "request.object"

Edit: Okay i figured it out, but now the question is how do i reinitialize the process request in a view based on different conditions.

For example:
It starts off as a default of

```
def process_request(self,request):
     request.object = Object.objects.get(id=1)
```

But based on a specific thing that happens in the views, i want it to change to a different id?

Comment: You create another piece of middleware, where you set an attribute on the `request` object.

Comment: I suspect the session would be a more appropriate place though.